# "dreimal so groß wie" vs. "dreimal größer als"

Tags: difference, grammaticality, comparison

Beim Lesen des Romans "Die Arbeit der Nacht", vom Thomas Glavinic, bin ich auf den folgenden Satz gestoßen:

"Staunend bemerkte er, dass Frau Benders Wohnung fast dreimal so groß gewesen war wie die seiner Familie."

Warum heißt hier "dreimal so groß wie" und nicht "dreimal größer als"? Ich bin zwar kein Muttersprachler, aber hätte mich zweifellos für die zweite Möglichkeit entschieden. Sind wohl beide richtig?

Comment: Ich halte "dreimal größer als" immer noch für einen Anglizismus.

Comment: Ich halte "dreimal größer als" für schlechtes Deutsch, weil die intendierte Bedeutung von Sprecher zu Sprecher variiert. Verschiedene Hörer werden es demgemäß unterschiedlich verstehen.

Comment: Lustig wird es bei der gleichen Formulierung mit "klein": Was bitte soll dreimal so klein bedeuten - wäre mathematisch das "-2fache", also weniger als nichts. Liest man aber überall, wo von einem Drittel die Rede ist...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Zunächst einmal: Die Formulierungen "dreimal so groß wie" und "dreimal größer als" haben unterschiedliche Bedeutungen:

- **"X ist dreimal so groß wie Y":** In diesem Fall gilt, was die Größe angeht, X = 3Y, denn das "dreimal" bezieht sich auf die absolute Größe von X.
- **"X ist dreimal größer als Y":** In diesem Fall gilt X = Y + 3Y = 4Y, denn das "dreimal" bezieht sich auf den durch "größer" angegebenen Größenunterschied.

Umgangssprachlich mögen die Bedeutungen allerdings von manchen Sprechern durchaus vermischt werden.

Davon abgesehen macht es aber keinen echten Unterschied, welche der Formulierungen man verwendet. Man könnte allenfalls sagen, dass man bei Vergleichen statischer Dinge (die Größen der Wohnungen ändern sich nicht) eher zur ersten Formulierung tendiert, während Vergleiche von dynamischen Angaben ("Er hatte aus Müdigkeit schon aufgegeben, ich bin noch dreimal weiter gelaufen als er.") eher die zweite Formulierung passend erscheinen lassen.

Comment: Ich (und viele andere) bevorzuge "n mal so groß", weil es im Unterschied zu "n mal größer" eindeutig ist. Ausführlich (aber vielleicht nicht repräsentiv) : http://www.sprache-werner.info/Komparativ-Gesamtfassung.30993.html

Comment: @IngoBochmann Ich muss dem widersprechen. Der Ausdruck "_n_ mal größer als" ist genauso _eindeutig_ wie "_n_ mal so groß wie" – sprachlich und mathematisch. Wie dargelegt wurde, bedeutet er bei festem _n_ einfach nur etwas anderes. Der Ausdruck wird nicht dadurch _mehrdeutig_, dass Sprecher ihn fehlinterpretieren, egal wie viele es sein mögen.

Comment: @Björn Link gelesen? Oder wenigstens überflogen? Sowohl alle meine Mathelehrer als auch Dozenten haben uns den Ausdruck "n mal größer" verboten; er ward gebrandmarkt als von unwissenschaftlichen Journalisten immer wieder (falsch) verwendet.

Comment: @IngoBochmann Ja, ich habe ihn gelesen. Tatsächlich kannte ich Herrn Werners Seite schon vorher. Nur ändert es nichts, nur weil Herr Werner das sagt. Wobei ich darauf hindeuten muss, dass Herr Werner gar nicht behauptet, dass der Ausdruck selbst mehrdeutig wäre, sondern dass die **falsche Annahme**, "viermal mehr ergäbe das Vierfache des Ausgangswertes", zu mehrdeutigen Aussagen führe (vgl. letzter Satz im ersten Absatz, sowie zweiter Absatz). Schließlich plädiert er für die Verwendung von "um so und so viel" oder "auf so und so viel", um der häufigen Fehlinterpretation aus dem Wege zu gehen.

Answer (score 1):

Sinnvoll sind folgende Aussagen:

1. A ist x-mal so groß wie B.
2. A ist um x Prozent größer als B.

Mit diesen beiden Aussagen kann man alle einschlägigen Phänomene sauber und klar beschreiben!
Korrekt ist auch die Aussage:

3. A ist um das x-Fache größer als B.
   Was synonym ist zur Aussage:
   A ist (x+1)-mal so groß wie B.

Die Aussagemöglichkeit

4. „A ist x-mal größer als B“

stiftet dagegen Verwirrung und ist komplett unnötig und überflüssig, wahrscheinlich sogar sinnfrei. Sinnfrei klingt in meinen Ohren zumindest eine Aussage wie:

> „A ist einmal größer als B“.

Was soll denn das bedeuten?

Selbst dass kluge, gebildete Leute die Aussage „A ist x-mal größer als B“ verteidigen, indem sie sie definieren als

> „A ist um das x-Fache größer als B“,

macht die Sache nicht besser. Dann sagt es halt bitte gleich so. Oder sagt am besten:

> A ist (x+1)-mal so groß wie B.

Dann muss man nicht jedesmal, wenn einer z. B. sagt:

> „Grundstück A ist zweieinhalb mal größer als Grundstück B“,

überlegen: Meint der auch das, was er sagt oder meint er was Anderes, als er sagt? Ist das erste Grundstück nun dreieinhalbmal oder doch nur zweieinhalbmal so groß wie das andere...

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. "Mein Apfel ist dreimal größer als Deiner" mag die Frage offen lassen, ob mein Apfel nun 300% oder 400% sind. (häufig begegnet mir die Annahme es seien 300%). Ich sehe in "x % größer als" irgendwie wenig Unterschied zu "x-mal größer als". Denn es wird unterstellt, dass bei der %-Angabe B die 100% sind und es deswegen präzise wird. Demnach müsste "einmal größer als" genauso sinnfrei sein wie "100% größer als"... Oder ist es das nicht? Wenn B 3 ist - wieviel ist dann "100% größer als" nach Definition dieser Antwort?

Comment: Bei der Frage, ob A oder B zu wählen ist, hilft es nicht wirklich weiter, B für sinnfrei zu erklären (ein diskussionswürdiger Standpunkt) und stattdessen C vorzuschlagen. Unstrittig ist: B kommt tatsächlich vor. Die Tatsache, dass die Wahrscheinlichkeit der korrekten Anwendung geringer ist, als bei anderen Formulierungen, kann man in Betracht ziehen, sie ist aber für die Entscheidung richtig oder falsch zweitrangig.

Comment: Wenn es um Sprache geht, kommt man mit Logik oft nicht sehr weit.Entscheidend ist der Sprachgebrauch.